Do line segments in an ambient $\mathbb{R}^n$ induce geodesic segments on a smooth submanifold?
Suppose I've got a geodesic living on some smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it always possible to chop up the geodesic into segments, so that each geodesic segment is induced by the ambient line segment between the endpoints of the geodesic segment?
The notion of induction I have in mind here is that for every point on the line segment, we find the nearest point on the submanifold, assuming that the choice is unique. The hope is that composing this map with a curve tracing out the line segment gives a curve tracing out the corresponding geodesic segment.
I don't currently know whether this is a plausible statement, but it is at least true for the sphere. I suspect it has been addressed in existing literature, but I had no luck finding a lead.
Additionally, if this statement is not true, is there some nearby modification of it that is true, which modifies the notion of induction?

Welcome to MSE! <> Offhand this property looks unlikely; presumably it works on spheres because geodesics are planar. I'd suggest checking what happens on a cylinder with a line segment joining two points at ends of a helical geodesic.

@AndrewD.Hwang
Thanks for the suggestion! A helical geodesic on a cylinder works as a counterexample.

If you can write up a proof, please do! (That is, answer your own question, don't edit the question to add an answer. :)

The conjectured statement is false. To see this, let's examine a helical geodesic on a cylinder embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, as the product of the unit circle in the xy-plane with the z-axis.
One particular helical geodesic in coordinates takes the form $(\cos(t), \sin(t), t)$. I'll show that no matter what small value of $t$ is chosen, the geodesic segment from $(1,0,0)$ to $(\cos(t), \sin(t), t)$ is not induced by a line segment in the conjectured fashion.
A general point on the segment between $(1,0,0)$ and $(\cos(t), \sin(t), t)$ has the form $q(\lambda) = (1-\lambda + \lambda \cos(t), \lambda \sin(t), \lambda t)$. Set $f(\lambda) = \sqrt{(1-\lambda)^2 + 2(1-\lambda)\lambda \cos(t) + \lambda^2}$, which is the norm of the projection of $q(\lambda)$ onto the xy-plane. For $|t| < \pi$, the nearest point to $q(\lambda)$ on the cylinder will be $p(\lambda) = \left(\frac{1-\lambda + \lambda \cos(t)}{f(\lambda)}, \frac{\lambda \sin(t)}{f(\lambda)}, \lambda t\right)$, since in general the nearest point on the cylinder to a point in the cylinder's interior will be a projection of the point onto the cylinder along the xy-plane, and the projection is unique when the point does not lie on the cylinder's axis of symmetry. The conjecture requires that $p(\lambda)$ equal $(\cos(t'), \sin(t'), t')$ for some choice of $t'$ — so only $t' = \lambda t$ is viable.
So the claim requires that $\frac{\lambda \sin(t)}{f(\lambda)} = \sin(\lambda t)$. This turns out to be true when $\lambda = 0.5$, but fixing $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\lambda = 0.25$, we have that $\frac{\lambda \sin(t)}{f(\lambda)\sin(\lambda t)} \approx 0.826 < 1$, as can be verified by direct calculation.
